# Label doesn't change until next method is done

Tags: c#, selenium, label, selenium-chromedriver

In my window I set the button that logs in the user to a site. After clicking the button it is supposed to change the `label.Content = "logging in..."`
 and then open chrome driver using selenium, logs into the site and after that it stops. The problem is label is not beeing changed until the next method is finished. But after next method I have another label change for success or failure which appears so basically the logging in label never appears on UI.

Take into consideration that my logging in works on the same thread as UI so the UI is not useable for logging time. But my label should've changed before program went to this state.

Also I tried putting label in method before it execute or adding `Thread.Sleep(2000);` to make a program wait for label to set. Didn't work.

And I tried changing the Thread of `sendusername()` and it gave me the label change, but then my login and password wasn't sent correctly.

What do You think might be the reason for that?

```
public void BtnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (TxtUsername.Text.Length<3 || TxtPassword.Text.Length<3)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You need to fill both boxes!");
    }
    else if (!TxtUsername.Text.Contains("@"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You need to add valiable e-mail adress");
    }
    else
    {
        LblLogin.Content = "Logging in..."; // changes label content
        sendUsername();  // opens chromedriver and logs us into the website
        ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).tradeUrl = tradeUrl;
        ((MainWindow) Application.Current.MainWindow).username = username;
        ((MainWindow) Application.Current.MainWindow).login = TxtUsername.Text;
        ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).password = TxtPassword.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that you have not accepted a single answer, on any of the questions you've asked here at Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Note that even if you answer the question yourself, you should accept the answer you post, so that the question is clearly indicated as having been addressed.

Comment: Note also that a high rate of questions without any answers at all suggests that you should spend some time working on improving your question-asking habits. This includes not asking questions that shouldn't be here, and making sure questions you do ask are well-presented. See [ask] and of course other links at https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking for additional details.

Answer (score 4):

Your BtnSubmit_OnClick() does not return a response until all the code inside the method executes, it's not actually real-time.

(1) You can either execute sendUserName asynchronously so your method does not have to wait for it to finish to return a response 
(2) Or you can just update the label content via JavaScript

For option #2, you can use the OnClientClick attribute to update the label text.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="updateLabel();" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: The first method will not do here, because it will just make my other functions stop working since this method sends data from textboxes. The second method will work I guess. But I need to learn how to do it quickly and will post later.

Comment: If that's the case then you can use the OnClientClick attribute in your button, specify the Javascript function to be called there.